# Java Fork Join Pool Eating All Thread Resources

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I have a string parser (parsing large text blobs) that needs to be run in a java fork join pool. The pool is faster than other threading and has reduced my parsing time by over 30 minutes when using both regular expressions and xpath. However, the number of threads being created climbs dramatically and I need to be able to terminate them since the thread pool is called multiple times.  How can I reduce the increase in threads without limiting the pool to just 1 core on a 4 core system?

My thread count is exceeding 40000 and I need it to be closer to 5000 since the program is running 10 times with a stone cold execution limit of 50000 threads for my user.

This issue is happening on both Windows and Linux.

I am:

- setting the max processors to the number of available processors*configurable number which is currently 1
- cancelling tasks after get() is called
- desperately setting the forkjoin pool to null before reinstantiating because I am desperate

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the code I am using to stop, get and restart the pool. I should probably also note that I am submitting each task with fjp.submit(TASK) and then invoking them all at shutdown.

while(pages.size()>0)
        {
            log.info("Currently Active Threads: "+Thread.activeCount());
            log.info("Pages Found in the Iteration "+j+": "+pages.size());

```
        if(fjp.isShutdown())
        {
            fjp=new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()*procnum);
        }

        i=0;
        //if asked to generate a hash, due this first
        if(getHash==true){
            log.info("Generating Hash");
            int s=pages.size();
            while(i<s){
                String withhash=null;
                String str=pages.get(0);

                if(str != null){
                    jmap=Json.read(str).asJsonMap();
                    jmap.put("offenderhash",Json.read(genHash(jmap.get("offenderhash").asString()+i)));

                    for(String k:jmap.keySet()){
                        withhash=(withhash==null)?"{\""+k+"\":\""+jmap.get(k).asString()+"\"":withhash+",\""+k+"\":\""+jmap.get(k).asString()+"\"";
                    }

                    if(withhash != null){
                        withhash+=",}";
                    }

                    pages.remove(0);
                    pages.add((pages.size()-1), withhash);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            i=0;
        }

        if(singlepats != null)
        {

        log.info("Found Singlepats");
        for(String row:pages)
        {   

            String str=row;
            str=str.replaceAll("\t|\r|\r\n|\n","");
            jmap=Json.read(str).asJsonMap();

            if(singlepats.containsKey("table"))
            {
                if(fjp.isShutdown())
                {
                    fjp=new ForkJoinPool((Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()*procnum));
                }

                fjp=new ForkJoinPool((Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()*procnum));

                if(jmap.get(column)!=null)
                {

                    if(test){
                        System.out.println("//////////////////////HTML////////////////////////\n"+jmap.get(column).asString()+"\n///////////////////////////////END///////////////////////////\n\n");
                    }

                    if(mustcontain != null)
                    {
                        if(jmap.get(column).asString().contains(mustcontain))
                        {
                            if(cannotcontain != null)
                            {
                                if(jmap.get(column).asString().contains(cannotcontain)==false)
                                results.add(fjp.submit(new ParsePage(replacementPattern,singlepats.get("table"),jmap.get(column).asString().replaceAll("\\s\\s", " "),singlepats, Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString(), jmap.get("offenderhash").asString())));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                results.add(fjp.submit(new ParsePage(replacementPattern,singlepats.get("table"),jmap.get(column).asString().replaceAll("\\s\\s", " "),singlepats, Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString(), jmap.get("offenderhash").asString())));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if(cannotcontain != null)
                    {
                        if(jmap.get(column).asString().contains(cannotcontain)==false)
                        {
                            results.add(fjp.submit(new ParsePage(replacementPattern,singlepats.get("table"),jmap.get(column).asString().replaceAll("\\s\\s", " "),singlepats, Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString(), jmap.get("offenderhash").asString())));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        results.add(fjp.submit(new ParsePage(replacementPattern,singlepats.get("table"),jmap.get(column).asString().replaceAll("\\s\\s", " "),singlepats, Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString(), jmap.get("offenderhash").asString())));
                    }
                }
            }

            i++;

            if(((i%commit_size)==0 & i != 0) | i==pages.size() |pages.size()==1 & singlepats != null)
            {
                log.info("Getting Regex Results");

                log.info("Shutdown");

                try {
                    fjp.awaitTermination(termtime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                fjp.shutdown();
                while(fjp.isTerminated()==false)
                {
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(5);
                    }catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                for(Future<String> r:results)
                {
                    try {
                        add=r.get();
                        if(add.contains("No Data")==false)
                        {
                            parsedrows.add(add);
                        }

                        add=null;
                        if(r.isDone()==false)
                        {
                            r.cancel(true);
                        }

                        if(fjp.getActiveThreadCount()>0 && fjp.getRunningThreadCount()>0)
                        {
                            fjp.shutdownNow();
                        }

                        fjp=new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()*procnum);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                results=new ArrayList<ForkJoinTask<String>>();

                if(parsedrows.size()>=commit_size)
                {

                    if(parsedrows.size()>=SPLITSIZE)
                    {
                        sendToDb(parsedrows,true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sendToDb(parsedrows,false);
                    }

                    parsedrows=new ArrayList<String>();
                }


                //hint to the gc in case it actually pays off (think if i were a gambling man)
                System.gc();
                Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
            }


        }
        }
        log.info("REMAINING ROWS TO COMMIT "+parsedrows.size());
        log.info("Rows Left"+parsedrows.size());
        if(parsedrows.size()>0)
        {


            if(parsedrows.size()>=SPLITSIZE)
            {
                sendToDb(parsedrows,true);
            }
            else
            {
                sendToDb(parsedrows,false);
            }


            parsedrows=new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        records+=i;
        i=0;

//Query for more records to parse
```

Comment: Can you post the full code or provide a links to pastebin?

Second question - why ForkJoinPool? In order to answer that question you need to find out whether parsing some string can be divided into parsing its substrings and somehow merging the results.

Comment: I added my code to the paste bin. The blobs cannot really be split further because of their nature. I am parsing them into fields from pretty much anywhere on the page

Comment: I am testing a solution and will post later. It is somewhat along the line of Pauls answer. I did not realize you could mix in Callables and that seems to know the threads down from 40000 to 39.  I just need to make sure they are still unique. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're making a new ForkJoinPool for every result. What you really want to do is make a single ForkJoinPool that all your tasks will share. Extra pools won't make extra parallelism available, so one should be fine. When you get a task that is ready to run take your fjp and call `fjp.execute(ForkJoinTask)` or `ForkJoinTask.fork()` if you're in a task already.

Making multiple pools seems like a bookkeeping nightmare. Try to get away with just one that's shared.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still did not solve the problem. I edited my code. I have to reinstantiate my pool to avoid a heap space issue but I reinstantiate after everything is complete.

Comment: This was the most correct answer. I added callables and was able to remove the shutdown and maintain speed. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

You are probably using join() in Java7. Join doesn't work. It requires a context switch and Java programs can't do a context switch so the framework creates "continuation threads" to keep moving. I detailed that problem several years ago in this article: [ForkJoin Clamamity](http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html#faulty)

Comment: My mistake on this post. The code is only a snippet and doesn't compile so I missed the meaning.